# Getting error "Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements"

Tags: java, database, hibernate, rest

I have been developing a REST API and I just can't seem to get rid of this error.

> nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException:
>    Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or 
>    @CollectionOfElements: com.example.TNDservice.Entity.HotelEntity.HotelId

Code:

```
public class HotelEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int Id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "hotelCon")
    @Column(name = "HOTELID")
    private String HotelId;


    public String getHotelId() {
        return HotelId;
    }

    public void setHotelId(String hotelId) {
        HotelId = hotelId;
    }
}

 public class ContractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int Id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "T522_HOTEL_HOTELID")
    private HotelEntity hotelCon;
}
```

Comment: Well, the exception clearly states that you are trying to use a mapping reserved for collections to map a non collection type of element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up realizing that the fault was that I have two Id's, one generated and one assigned. I ended up taking one of them off like so,

```
public class HotelEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "HOTELID")
    private String HotelId;

public class ContractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "CONTRACTID")
    private String ContractId;
}
```

I decided to keep the ID as auto-generated.

Answer (score 0):

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "hotelCon") @Column(name = "HOTELID") 
private String HotelId;
```

As name suggests one to many relationship map one object to multiple objects, hence you are not supposed to have this

```
private String HotelId ;
```

Instead of

```
private Collection<Entity name> listOfEntity ;
```

Variable name should start with lowercase. Please go through the basic concepts and documentation.